# How to decode the packet which is decrypted SSL in wireshark?

Tags: wireshark, tls1.2

everyone. I am working a MQTT connection by using TLSv1.2 with the server.

Before asking the question, I've spend sometime to googling the answer. But all the answers I found are talking about how to decrypt SSL trafic in wireshark. This part is done successfully. My question is , after I successfully decrypted the data by setting the CLIENT RANDOM and MASTER SECRET in a file and set it up in TLS deocoding settings in Wireshark, how to decode the decrypted data?

For all decoded data, Wireshark show as seperated tab named as "Decrypted TLS". Once I click the tab, it only shows the raw data as HEX.

Can I ask Wireshark to further decode the raw data by using known protocol such as MQTT?

Comment: There should be an option for "decode as" if you right click on a PDU.

Comment: Thanks. I used to use "decode as" for some ports that not normally matched as protocal port. Now I found it works after the decryption! Great! I think you solved my problem and I'd like to close the issue. But if there is no answer for the question I cannot make it as solved. Would you please copy the comment as an answer? Thanks.